# How to aggregate query result in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new in elasticsearch. I want elasticsearch result be like following sql query,

```
select distinct(car_name) from car_master where car_name like '%SUV%'
```

I am getting result by doing:

```
{ "query": {
    "query_string": {
    "fields" : ["car_name"],
    "query": "*SUV*"
    }
  }
}
```

but I want distinct records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, you simply need to add a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on the `car_name` field:

```
{ 
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
    "fields" : ["car_name"],
    "query": "*SUV*"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "cars": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "car_name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```